# Phonegap device plugins doesn't work

Tags: android, cordova, phonegap-plugins

First of all, I must to say I did try many ways in another asked questions in stackoverflow but I did not solve my problem.

I'm developing a phonegap android app but the plugins I've attached to it doesn't works.

My index.html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<!--
Licensed to the Apache Software Foundation (ASF) under one
or more contributor license agreements.  See the NOTICE file
distributed with this work for additional information
regarding copyright ownership.  The ASF licenses this file
to you under the Apache License, Version 2.0 (the
"License"); you may not use this file except in compliance
with the License.  You may obtain a copy of the License at
http://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0
Unless required by applicable law or agreed to in writing,
software distributed under the License is distributed on an
"AS IS" BASIS, WITHOUT WARRANTIES OR CONDITIONS OF ANY
 KIND, either express or implied.  See the License for the
specific language governing permissions and limitations
under the License.
-->
<html>
    <head>
    <!--
    Customize this policy to fit your own app's needs. For more guidance, see:
        https://github.com/apache/cordova-plugin-whitelist/blob/master/README.md#content-security-policy
    Some notes:
        * gap: is required only on iOS (when using UIWebView) and is needed for JS->native communication
        * https://ssl.gstatic.com is required only on Android and is needed for TalkBack to function properly
        * Disables use of inline scripts in order to mitigate risk of XSS vulnerabilities. To change this:
            * Enable inline JS: add 'unsafe-inline' to default-src
    -->
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Security-Policy" content="default-src 'self' data: gap: https://ssl.gstatic.com 'unsafe-eval'; style-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline'; media-src *">
    <meta name="format-detection" content="telephone=no">
    <meta name="msapplication-tap-highlight" content="no">
    <meta name="viewport" content="user-scalable=no, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, minimum-scale=1, width=device-width">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/bootstrap.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/bootstrap-theme.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/sidebar.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/index.css">
    <title>Restaurante do João</title>
</head>
<body>

    <div class="page-container">
        <!-- top navbar -->
        <div class="navbar navbar-default navbar-fixed-top" role="navigation">
           <div class="container">
            <div class="navbar-header">
               <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="offcanvas" data-target=".sidebar-nav">
                 <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                 <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                 <span class="icon-bar"></span>
               </button>
               <a class="navbar-brand" href="#"><span style="font-size:12px; color: #fff; font-weight: bold;">Restaurante do João</span></a>
            </div>
           </div>
        </div>

      <div class="container">
        <div class="row row-offcanvas row-offcanvas-left background-el">

            <!-- sidebar -->
            <div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-3 sidebar-offcanvas" id="sidebar" role="navigation">
                <ul class="nav" style="margin-top:50px;">
                  <li><a class="menuLink active" id="home" href="#">Home</a></li>
                  <li><a class="menuLink" id="cardapio" href="#">Cardapio</a></li>
                <li><a class="menuLink" id="link2" href="#">Link 2</a></li>
                  <li><a class="menuLink" id="link3" href="#">Link 3</a></li>            
                <li><a href="#" onclick="alert('Browser alert'); return false;">Show browser Alert</a></li>
                  <li><a href="#" onclick="showConfirmation(); return false;">Show Confirmation</a></li>
                  <li><a href="#" onclick="showAlert(); return false;">Show Alert</a></li>
                  <li><a href="#" onclick="playBeep(); return false;">Play Beep</a></li>
                <li><a  href="#" onclick="javascript:navigator.notification.vibrate(2000); return false;">Vibrate</a></li>
                </ul>
            </div>
            <script>
            </script>
            <!-- main area -->
            <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-9">
                <div class="row" id="divContent">

                </div>
            </div><!-- /.col-xs-12 main -->
        </div><!--/.row-->
      </div><!--/.container-->
    </div><!--/.page-container-->

    <!--<div class="app">
        <h1>Apache Cordova</h1>
        <div id="deviceready" class="blink">
            <p class="event listening">Connecting to Device</p>
            <p class="event received">Device is Ready</p>
        </div>
    </div>-->
    <script type="text/javascript" src="cordova.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/index.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-1.11.3.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/bootstrap.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/Utils.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

My config.xml (in the www folder)

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8'?>
<widget id="com.phonegap.helloworld" version="1.0.0" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/ns/widgets" xmlns:gap="http://phonegap.com/ns/1.0">
<name>Hello World</name>
<description>
    Hello World sample application that responds to the deviceready event.
</description>
<author email="support@phonegap.com" href="http://phonegap.com">
    PhoneGap Team
</author>
<content src="index.html" />
<preference name="permissions" value="none" />
<preference name="orientation" value="default" />
<preference name="target-device" value="universal" />
<preference name="fullscreen" value="true" />
<preference name="webviewbounce" value="true" />
<preference name="prerendered-icon" value="true" />
<preference name="stay-in-webview" value="false" />
<preference name="ios-statusbarstyle" value="black-opaque" />
<preference name="detect-data-types" value="true" />
<preference name="exit-on-suspend" value="false" />
<preference name="show-splash-screen-spinner" value="true" />
<preference name="auto-hide-splash-screen" value="true" />
<preference name="disable-cursor" value="false" />
<preference name="android-minSdkVersion" value="14" />
<preference name="android-installLocation" value="auto" />
<gap:plugin name="org.apache.cordova.battery-status" />
<gap:plugin name="org.apache.cordova.camera" />
<gap:plugin name="org.apache.cordova.media-capture" />
<gap:plugin name="org.apache.cordova.console" />
<gap:plugin name="org.apache.cordova.contacts" />
<gap:plugin name="org.apache.cordova.device" />
<gap:plugin name="org.apache.cordova.device-motion" />
<gap:plugin name="org.apache.cordova.device-orientation" />
<gap:plugin name="org.apache.cordova.dialogs" />
<gap:plugin name="org.apache.cordova.file" />
<gap:plugin name="org.apache.cordova.file-transfer" />
<gap:plugin name="org.apache.cordova.geolocation" />
<gap:plugin name="org.apache.cordova.globalization" />
<gap:plugin name="org.apache.cordova.inappbrowser" />
<gap:plugin name="org.apache.cordova.media" />
<gap:plugin name="org.apache.cordova.network-information" />
<gap:plugin name="org.apache.cordova.splashscreen" />
<gap:plugin name="org.apache.cordova.vibration" />
<icon src="icon.png" />
<icon gap:platform="android" gap:qualifier="ldpi" src="www/res/icon/android/icon-36-ldpi.png" />
<icon gap:platform="android" gap:qualifier="mdpi" src="www/res/icon/android/icon-48-mdpi.png" />
<icon gap:platform="android" gap:qualifier="hdpi" src="www/res/icon/android/icon-72-hdpi.png" />
<icon gap:platform="android" gap:qualifier="xhdpi" src="www/res/icon/android/icon-96-xhdpi.png" />
<icon gap:platform="blackberry" src="www/res/icon/blackberry/icon-80.png" />
<icon gap:platform="blackberry" gap:state="hover" src="www/res/icon/blackberry/icon-80.png" />
<icon gap:platform="ios" height="57" src="www/res/icon/ios/icon-57.png" width="57" />
<icon gap:platform="ios" height="72" src="www/res/icon/ios/icon-72.png" width="72" />
<icon gap:platform="ios" height="114" src="www/res/icon/ios/icon-57-2x.png" width="114" />
<icon gap:platform="ios" height="144" src="www/res/icon/ios/icon-72-2x.png" width="144" />
<icon gap:platform="webos" src="www/res/icon/webos/icon-64.png" />
<icon gap:platform="winphone" src="www/res/icon/windows-phone/icon-48.png" />
<icon gap:platform="winphone" gap:role="background" src="www/res/icon/windows-phone/icon-173-tile.png" />
<gap:splash gap:platform="android" gap:qualifier="port-ldpi" src="www/res/screen/android/screen-ldpi-portrait.png" />
<gap:splash gap:platform="android" gap:qualifier="port-mdpi" src="www/res/screen/android/screen-mdpi-portrait.png" />
<gap:splash gap:platform="android" gap:qualifier="port-hdpi" src="www/res/screen/android/screen-hdpi-portrait.png" />
<gap:splash gap:platform="android" gap:qualifier="port-xhdpi" src="www/res/screen/android/screen-xhdpi-portrait.png" />
<gap:splash gap:platform="blackberry" src="www/res/screen/blackberry/screen-225.png" />
<gap:splash gap:platform="ios" height="480" src="www/res/screen/ios/screen-iphone-portrait.png" width="320" />
<gap:splash gap:platform="ios" height="960" src="www/res/screen/ios/screen-iphone-portrait-2x.png" width="640" />
<gap:splash gap:platform="ios" height="1136" src="www/res/screen/ios/screen-iphone-portrait-568h-2x.png" width="640" />
<gap:splash gap:platform="ios" height="1024" src="www/res/screen/ios/screen-ipad-portrait.png" width="768" />
<gap:splash gap:platform="ios" height="768" src="www/res/screen/ios/screen-ipad-landscape.png" width="1024" />
<gap:splash gap:platform="winphone" src="www/res/screen/windows-phone/screen-portrait.jpg" />
<access origin="*" />
<plugin name="cordova-plugin-whitelist" version="1" />
<allow-intent href="http://*/*" />
<allow-intent href="https://*/*" />
<allow-intent href="tel:*" />
<allow-intent href="sms:*" />
<allow-intent href="mailto:*" />
<allow-intent href="geo:*" />
<platform name="android">
    <allow-intent href="market:*" />
</platform>
<platform name="ios">
    <allow-intent href="itms:*" />
    <allow-intent href="itms-apps:*" />
</platform>
</widget>
```

In the "Plugins" tab of phonegap app page, there are some plugins.
See it in this screenshot

http://prntscr.com/8bezzy

On mobile, when installing, the permissions of the app is shown but when I open the app and click in one of the buttons to call some native functionality, it doesn't work.

Am I forgetting something?

Thanks

Comment: Is there any error? because image shows that plugins are installed. And what specific plugin is not working?

Comment: This time I trying vibrate. In index.html code above, there is a button that calls vibrate functionality. No errors. The installation is ok and no feedback on button click.

Answer (score 2):

Please use `navigator.vibrate(2000);` for vibration.

```
<li><a  href="#" onclick="javascript:navigator.vibrate(2000);">Vibrate</a></li>
```

And go through vibration plugin to see its functions and use :
https://github.com/apache/cordova-plugin-vibration

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I tested with navigator.vibrate but still the same.
I will try reinstalling the vibration plugin and let you know.

Comment: @MárcioGonzalez you are adding too many plugins at a time and i can't tell which is making this problem, as far as i have observed from your code, you should test plugins one by one.

Comment: or send me build link so i can tell you which plugin is making problem.

Comment: Try this link 
https://build.phonegap.com/apps/1629132/download/android?qr_key=uCzr6vxhMj9smoox712m

  If it doesn't works, let me know to generate another one

Comment: Did you change something?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/88601/discussion-between-marcio-gonzalez-and-mudasser-ajaz).

Answer (score 0):

Try adding these two lines to your config.xml

```
<preference name="android-minSdkVersion"      value="7" />
<preference name="phonegap-version" value="3.7.0" />
```